# React Grid Layout - change property dynamically

Tags: reactjs, grid

I'm trying to toggle a `"static"` property using local state variable, but it doesn't work for me.

I am using React Grid Layout to drag and drop elements. An example of such an element:

```
<div 
    key={"id" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2)} 
    data-grid={{ x: 4, y: 0, w: 2, h: 2 }} 
    style={{ width: '150px', height: '40px', backgroundColor: "#ccc", color: "#fff" }}
>
    Поле ввода
</div>
```

One of the elements creates a new grid layout inside the existing one:

```
<div 
    key={"id" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2)} 
    onClick={doubleClickHandler}
    data-grid={{ x: 1, y: 0, w: 5, h: 7, isResizable: isStatic ? false : true, static: isStatic }} 
    style={{ backgroundColor: "#759ad9", color: "#fff" }}
>
    <GridLayout 
        className="layout"
        cols={5}
        rowHeight={30}
        width={650}
    >
        { mock }
    </GridLayout>
</div>
```

The problem is that I can only move items inside the child grid when its `static` parameter is true. I tried to create a local state and change the isStatic variable on double click on the grid. The value of the variable changes, but the grid does not become fixed. At the same time, if I just set static: true in the code without any conditions, then the elements inside the child grid can be moved. What could be the problem? Full code is:

```
import { Menu } from 'antd';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { GridWrapper } from '../Base/Base';
import GridLayout from "react-grid-layout";

function FormConstructor() {
    const items = [
        { label: 'Input', key: 'item-1' },
        // другие элементы
        { label: 'Field', key: 'item-8' },
    ];

    // a variable that changes but does not affect the grid as want it to
    const [isStatic, setIsStatic] = useState(false)
    // parent grid elements
    const [elemsList, setElemsList] = useState([])
    // child grid elements
    const mock = [
        <div 
            // props
        >
            Поле ввода
        </div>,
        <div 
            // props
        >
            Поле ввода
        </div>,
    ]

    // double click handler that should make the child grid static. It does change the state variable, but the grid is still not affected
    const doubleClickHandler = e => {
        if (e.detail === 2) setIsStatic(true)
    }

    const handleClick = val => {
        if (val === 'item-1') {
            setElemsList(elemsList.concat(
                <div 
                    key={"id" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2)} 
                    data-grid={{ x: 4, y: 0, w: 2, h: 2 }} 
                    style={{ width: '150px', height: '40px', backgroundColor: "#ccc", color: "#fff" }}
                    resizeHandles={['s' | 'w' | 'e' | 'n' | 'sw' | 'nw' | 'se' | 'ne']}
                >
                    Поле ввода
                </div>
            ));
        // other elems
        } else if (val === 'item-8') {
            setElemsList(elemsList.concat(
                <div 
                    key={"id" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2)} 
                    onClick={doubleClickHandler}
                    data-grid={{ x: 1, y: 0, w: 5, h: 7, isResizable: isStatic ? false : true, static: isStatic ? true : false }} 
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#759ad9", color: "#fff" }}
                >
                    <GridLayout 
                        className="layout"
                        cols={5}
                        rowHeight={30}
                        width={650}
                    >
                        { mock }
                    </GridLayout>
                </div>
            ))
        }       
    }

    // return elems
    return (
        <div style={{display: "flex", height: "100%"}}>
            <GridWrapper options={{style: "width: calc(100% - 300px)"}}>
                <GridLayout 
                    className="layout"
                    cols={12}
                    rowHeight={30}
                    width={1600}
                >
                    { elemsList }
                </GridLayout>
            </GridWrapper>
            <Menu 
                items={items}
                style={{ width: "300px", float: "right", border: "1px solid #D4D1E8", borderRadius: "7px", zIndex: 9000 }} 
                onClick={e => handleClick(e.key)}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Note: the value of a local state DOES change, but already existing element will not become fixed. At the same time, the next created element will have the changed value. Is there any chance to toggle "static" property of already existing element?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case somebody will have the same issue, I think I have a solution. I'll just post my entire componet:

```
import { Menu } from 'antd';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { GridWrapper } from '../Base/Base';
import GridLayout from "react-grid-layout";

function FormConstructor() {
    const items = [
        { label: 'Input', key: 'item-1' },
        { label: 'Checkbox', key: 'item-2' },
        { label: 'Radio', key: 'item-3' },
        { label: 'Button', key: 'item-4' },
        { label: 'Select', key: 'item-5' },
        { label: 'Date picker', key: 'item-6' },
        { label: 'Upload', key: 'item-7' },
        { label: 'Field', key: 'item-8' },
    ];

    const [elemsList, setElemsList] = useState([])
    const [layout, setLayout] = useState([
        { i: "a", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true, },
        { i: "b", x: 1, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true, },
        { i: "c", x: 2, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true, },
        { i: "d", x: 0, y: 1, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true, },
        { i: "e", x: 1, y: 1, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true, },
        { i: "f", x: 2, y: 1, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true, },
        { i: "g", x: 0, y: 2, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true, },
        { i: "h", x: 1, y: 2, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true, },
        { i: "i", x: 2, y: 2, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true, },
    ]);
    
    const mock = [
        <div 
            key="a" 
            data-grid={{ x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true }} 
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#ccc", color: "#fff", height: "100%" }}
        >
            Поле ввода
        </div>,
        <div 
            key="d"
            data-grid={{ x: 0, y: 1, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true }} 
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#ccc", color: "#fff", height: "100%" }}
        >
            Кнопка
        </div>
    ];

    const handleClick = val => {
        if (val === 'item-1') {
            setElemsList(elemsList.concat(
                <div 
                    key="a" 
                    data-grid={{ x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true }} 
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#ccc", color: "#fff", height: "100%" }}
                >
                    Поле ввода
                </div>
            ));
        } else if (val === 'item-2') {
            setElemsList(elemsList.concat(
                <div 
                    key="b"
                    data-grid={{ x: 1, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true }} 
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#ccc", color: "#fff", height: "100%" }}
                >
                    Множетвенный выбор
                </div>
            ))
        } else if (val === 'item-3') {
            setElemsList(elemsList.concat(
                <div 
                    key="c" 
                    data-grid={{ x: 2, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true }} 
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#ccc", color: "#fff", height: "100%" }}
                >
                    Единый выбор
                </div>
            ))
        } else if (val === 'item-4') {
            setElemsList(elemsList.concat(
                <div 
                    key="d"
                    data-grid={{ x: 0, y: 1, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true }} 
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#ccc", color: "#fff", height: "100%" }}
                >
                    Кнопка
                </div>
            ))
        } else if (val === 'item-5') {
            setElemsList(elemsList.concat(
                <div 
                    key="e"
                    data-grid={{ x: 1, y: 1, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true }} 
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#ccc", color: "#fff", height: "100%" }}
                >
                    Выбор из перечня
                </div>
            ))
        } else if (val === 'item-6') {
            setElemsList(elemsList.concat(
                <div 
                    key="f"
                    data-grid={{ x: 2, y: 1, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true }} 
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#ccc", color: "#fff", height: "100%" }}
                >
                    Выбор даты
                </div>
            ))
        } else if (val === 'item-7') {
            setElemsList(elemsList.concat(
                <div 
                    key="g"
                    data-grid={{ x: 0, y: 2, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true }} 
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#ccc", color: "#fff", height: "100%" }}
                >
                    Загрузка файла
                </div>
            ))
        } else if (val === 'item-8') {
            setElemsList(elemsList.concat(
                <div
                    key="h"
                    data-grid={{ x: 1, y: 2, w: 1, h: 1, static: false }} 
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#ccc", color: "#fff", height: "100%" }}
                >
                        <GridLayout 
                            className="layout"
                            cols={5}
                            rowHeight={30}
                            width={650}
                        >
                            { mock }
                        </GridLayout>
                </div>
            ))
        }       
    }

    const fixLayout = (layout) => {
        const maxY = 11;
    
        const maxRowXs = layout
          .map((item) => (item.y === maxY ? item.x : null))
          .filter((value) => value !== null);
    
        const xs = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
    
        const missingX = xs.find((value) =>
          maxRowXs.every((maxRowX) => maxRowX !== value)
        );
    
        const fixedLayout = layout.map((item) => {
          if (item.y > maxY) {
            const fixedItem = {
              ...item,
              y: maxY,
              x: missingX,
            };
            return fixedItem;
          }
          return item;
        });
        return fixedLayout;
    };

    return (
            <div style={{display: "flex", height: "100%"}}>
                <GridWrapper options={{style: "width: calc(100% - 300px)"}}>
                    <GridLayout 
                        className="layout"
                        cols={24}
                        rowHeight={30}
                        width={1600}
                        maxRows={12}
                        layout={layout}
                        onLayoutChange={e => setLayout(fixLayout(e))}
                    >
                        { elemsList.map((item, i) => (
                            <div key={i}>{item}</div>
                        )) }
                    </GridLayout>
                </GridWrapper>
                <Menu 
                    items={items}
                    style={{ width: "300px", float: "right", border: "1px solid #D4D1E8", borderRadius: "7px", zIndex: 9000 }} 
                    onClick={e => handleClick(e.key)}
                />
            </div>
    )
}

export default FormConstructor
```